# Append a list in main from a defined class

Tags: python, python-3.x

The purpose of this assignment is to define a class in Python and use it to create an object and display its components. I've already created a class that creates an Inventory item and display information but I'm having trouble in my main class appending the inventory list and displaying user friendly information. I feel like this is something easy to achieve but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's what I have so far.

```
class InventoryItem(object):
    def __init__(self, description, unit_cost, items_in_stock):
        self.description = description
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost
        self.items_in_stock = items_in_stock
        print('Description: ' + self.description)
        print('Item Costs: ' + str(self.unit_cost))
        print('Number in stock: ' + str(self.items_in_stock))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inventory_list = []
    cookies = InventoryItem('Cookies', 5.00, 24)

    print(inventory_list)
    inventory_list.append(cookies)
    print(inventory_list)
```

The output that I am getting is this:

```
Description: Cookies
Item Costs: 5.0 
Number in stock: 24 
[]
[<__main__.InventoryItem object at 0x00E85A10>]
```

The first part is as expected except I don't know why it seems to show the memory location of that data? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a better string representation of your `InventoryItem`, implement the `__repr__` method on it.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when you print the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two magic methods called the `__str__` and `__repr__` which are meant to be used in situations like this. By default, if not overridden, printing an object will just print it's memory contents in the format you see `<...>`.

The difference? `__repr__` prints the representation of an object (such as inside the list). `__str__` is what you see when you call `print()` on that object.

```
class InventoryItem(object):
    def __init__(self, description, unit_cost, items_in_stock):
        self.description = description
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost
        self.items_in_stock = items_in_stock

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'Description: ' + self.description + '\n'
        string += 'Item Costs: ' + str(self.unit_cost) + '\n'
        string += 'Number in stock: ' + str(self.items_in_stock)

        return string

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inventory_list = []
    cookies = InventoryItem('Cookies', 5.00, 24)

    print(inventory_list)
    inventory_list.append(cookies)
    print(inventory_list)
```

Output:

```
[]
[Description: Cookies
Item Costs: 5.0
Number in stock: 24]
```

Let's change things up a bit now in the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. This'll help you understand the difference between the two.

```
class InventoryItem(object):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'Description: ' + self.description + '\n'
        string += 'Item Costs: ' + str(self.unit_cost) + '\n'
        string += 'Number in stock: ' + str(self.items_in_stock)

        return string

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Hi!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inventory_list = []
    cookies = InventoryItem('Cookies', 5.00, 24)

    print(inventory_list)
    inventory_list.append(cookies)
    print(inventory_list)
```

This prints:

```
[]
[Hi!]
```

Now, if you call `print(cookies)`, you get this:

```
Description: Cookies
Item Costs: 5.0
Number in stock: 24
```

Do ensure that you return valid `str` objects from those methods, if you choose to implement them in your class.

Comment: Awesome... I get it now, great response/answer! I think I must have skipped reading about this in a textbook somewhere.

Comment: @MattCom Yup, these are indispensable if you want to write good, maintainable classes that convey their purpose/meaning to whoever prints them.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is override the `__repr__` method of your class.

Like so:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Description: ' + self.description + ', Item Costs: ' + str(self.unit_cost) + ', Number in stock: ' + str(self.items_in_stock)
```